# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' in sql server 2012 when executing SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis

> Could not load package "\MSDB\MySSISPackage" because of error
>   0×80131500. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

This is the error I get when I run my ssis package through a sql job. We are using NTLM Authentication. Checked everywhere for an answer. None of the the solutions work for me. Please help.

[update]: We are on a clustered sql environment with active (server a)/passive cluster (server b). SSIS is on the passive sql server (server a) and we cannot access SSIS on the active sql server (server b).

On the active sql server (on server b), when we try to connect to SSIS package, we get "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' " error.
On the active sql server (server b) integrated services is not installed so we can not update MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml with the default instance of sql.    How do we on server b access SSIS on server a? so that is uses the configuration of server A.

Detailed error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The SQL Server instance specified in SSIS service configuration is not present or is not available. This might occur when there is no default instance of SQL Server on the computer. For more information, see the topic "Configuring the Integration Services Service" in SQL Server 2012 Books Online.

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (MsDtsSrvr)

---

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: Have you created an [SSIS proxy account](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)?

Comment: Try this - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30074/login-failure-when-running-a-ssis-package-from-a-sql-server-job

Comment: We did try the SSIS proxy and even tried the steps detailed in the below blog: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3086/how-to-resolve-ssis-access-denied-error-in-sql-server-management-studio/ None of these helped. We are still stuck with the Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error. Please help. Thanks.